# Drop constraint names received from different query

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm trying to drop a few constraints which have been automatically generated when I add the default value somewhere.

I use the following script to return me the names of the constraints:

```
SELECT default_constraints.name FROM sys.all_columns
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON all_columns.object_id = tables.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints ON all_columns.default_object_id = default_constraints.object_id
WHERE tables.name = 'TrainingType'
AND default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingT__Soft__%'
OR default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingT__EndUs__%'
OR default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingC__Compu__%'
```

This returns me the following:

```
  | name
---------------------------------
1 | DF__TrainingC__Compu__2058C9F1
2 | DF__TrainingT__EndUs__1559B68C
3 | DF__TrainingT__Softw__05CD5A39
```

Now I'm trying to drop the constraints with these values, but it doesn't allow me to do `DROP CONSTRAINT ( ... )`

```
ALTER TABLE TrainingType
DROP CONSTRAINT (
    SELECT default_constraints.name FROM sys.all_columns
    INNER JOIN sys.tables ON all_columns.object_id = tables.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints ON all_columns.default_object_id = default_constraints.object_id
    WHERE tables.name = 'TrainingType'
    AND default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingT__Soft__%'
    OR default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingT__EndUs__%'
    OR default_constraints.name like 'DF__TrainingC__Compu__%'
)
```

So how can I drop the constraints correctly?

Comment: with dynamic sql

Comment: The drop constraint is expecting a static qualifier while you are trying to inject a dynamic one.

Comment: @SqlZim do you mean by using `EXEC`?

Comment: @RossBush I'm fully aware of this, but I'll never know the static qualifier as it will change every day and get a random number at the back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Sql using the [**`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) to concatenate the commands into one variable to execute with [**`sp_executesql`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = (
  select 
     'alter table '+quotename(schema_name(dc.schema_id))
    +'.'+quotename(object_name(dc.parent_object_id))
    +' drop constraint '+quotename(name)+';'+char(10)
  from sys.default_constraints as dc
  where parent_object_id = object_id(N'TrainingType')
    and dc.name like 'DF__TrainingT__Soft__%'
     or dc.name like 'DF__TrainingT__EndUs__%'
     or dc.name like 'DF__TrainingC__Compu__%'
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')

set @sql = 'use '+quotename(db_name())+';'+char(10)+@sql;
select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

This is a good primer on dynamic sql:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HSV25230

Generated code from the demo:

```
use [rextester];
alter table [dbo].[Pilots] drop constraint [DF__Pilots__df__173EF6DF];
alter table [dbo].[Pilots] drop constraint [DF__Pilots__other_df__18331B18];
```

Comment: I have honestly to god no idea what is happening in that query, but it's working haha

Comment: @JorisDecraecker I added a reference for the concatenation using `for xml path ('')`, and removed the `stuff()`, which I added out of force of habit. Usually there is a delimiter at the beginning of the string that you want removed before the first value being returned.

Comment: Alright i'm taking a look into this and it looks interesting. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll work once you add the ID as column and name as a second column.

This should be the proper syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name"
DROP [CONSTRAINT|INDEX] "CONSTRAINT_NAME";
```

Comment: I'll still only be able to get all these values dynamically and I'll never have the static values (like the syntax is asking now)

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject dynamic qualifiers into a drop clause like that. They have to be issued one at a time. A similar method would be to generate a script to run as individual sql commands.

```
SELECT
     'ALTER TABLE TrainingType DROP CONSTRAINT ( '
    + default_constraints.name +')'
    + CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+ GO '
FROM sys.all_columns
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON all_columns.object_id = tables.object_id
....
```

You now have one statement per drop command that you can apply against your database.